# multi-stage aggregation pipeline matching data based on fields retrieved through $lookup

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I'm trying to build a complex, nested aggregation pipeline in MongoDB (4.4.9 Community Edition, using the `pymongo` driver for Python 3.10).

There are relevant data points in different collections which I want to aggregate into one, NEW (ideally) view (or, if that doesn't work) collection.

The collections, and the relevant fields therein follow a hierarchy. There is `members`, which contains the top-level key on which other data is to be merged,
`membershipNumber`.

```
> members.find_one()
{'_id': ObjectId('61153299af6122XXXXXXXXXXXXX'), 'membershipNumber': 'N03XXXXXX'}
```

Then, there's a different collection, which contains `membershipNumber`, but also a different, linked field, `an_user_id`. `an_user_id` is used in other collections to denote records/fields in arrays that pertain to that particular user.

I 'join' `members` and `an_users` like so:

```
result = members.aggregate([
    {
        '$lookup': {
            'from': 'an_users',                   
            'localField': 'membershipNumber',     
            'foreignField': 'memref',             
            'as': 'an_users'                      
        }
    },
    {   '$unwind' : '$an_users' },     
    {   
        '$project' : {
            '_id' : 1,
            'membershipNumber' : 1,
            'an_user_id' : '$an_users.user_id'
        } 
    }
]);
```

So far so good, this returns the desired, aggregated record:

```
{'_id': ObjectId('61153253aBBBBBBBBBBBB'),
  'membershipNumber': 'N0XXXXXXXX',
  'an_user_id': '48XXXXXX'}
```

Now, I have a third collection, which contains the **`an_user_id`** as a string in arrays, denoting wherever that user clicked a given email, whereby a record is an email (and the `an_user_id`s in the `clicks` array are users that clicked a link in that email.

```
{'_id': ObjectId('blah'),
 'email_id': '407XXX',
 'actions_count': 17,
 'administrative_title': 'test',
 'bounce': ['3440XXXX'],
 'click': ['38294CCC',
  '418FFFF',
  '48XXXXXX',
  '38eGGGG'}
```

#### I want to count the number occurences of a given `an_user_id` (which I've attained from aggregating) in arrays (e.g. `clicks`, `bounces`, `opens`) in the `emails` collection, and include it in the `.aggregate` call, to retrieve something like this:

```
{'_id': ObjectId('61153253aBBBBBBBBBBBB'),
  'membershipNumber': 'N0XXXXXXXX',
  'an_user_id': '48XXXXXX',
  'n_email_clicks' : 412,
  'n_email_bounces' : 12
}
```

#### Further, I might want to also attach counts of `an_user_id` in other collections in my DB.

Consider, e.g., this collection called `events`:

```
{
    "_id": "617ffa96ee11844e143a63dd",
    "id": "12345",
    "administrative_title": "my_event",
    "created_at": {
        "$date": "2020-01-15T16:28:50.000Z"
    },
    "event_creator_id": "123456",
    "event_title": "my_event",
    "group_id": "123456",
    "permalink": "event_id",
    "rsvp_count": 54,
    "rsvps": [{
        "rsvp_id": "56789",
        "display_name": "John Doe",
        "rsvp_user_id": "48XXXXXX",
        "rsvp_created_at": {
            "$date": "2020-01-28T15:38:50.000Z"
        },
        "rsvp_updated_at": {
            "$date": "2020-01-28T15:38:50.000Z"
        },
        "first_name": "John",
        "last_name": "Doe",
    }, {
        "rsvp_id": "543895",
        "display_name": "James Appleslice",
        "rsvp_user_id": "N03XXXXXX",
        "rsvp_created_at": {
            "$date": "2020-02-05T13:15:14.000Z"
        },
        "rsvp_updated_at": {
            "$date": "2020-02-05T13:15:14.000Z"
        },
        "first_name": "James",
        "last_name": "Appleslice"}
  ]
}
```

So, the end-product would look something like this:

```
{'_id': ObjectId('61153253aBBBBBBBBBBBB'),
  'membershipNumber': 'N0XXXXXXXX',
  'an_user_id': '48XXXXXX',
  'n_email_clicks' : 412,
  'n_email_bounces' : 12,
  'n_rsvps' : 12
}
```

My idea was to use the `$lookup` parameter -- however, I only know how to use this for matching on fields that I have in the parent collection that I'm performing the aggregation on, but not on fields that have been generated in the process of the aggregation.

Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `$lookup` pipeline. First you would `$lookup` the user id followed by another `$lookup` to verify if the user id exists in email. Lastly few more stages to collect the results and format per your need. Furthermore, you can add `$out` stage if you would like to write the results into another collection.

```
db.members.aggregate([{
  $lookup: {
    from: "an_users",
    let: {
      membershipNumber: "$membershipNumber"
    },
    pipeline: [
      {
        $match: {
          $expr: {
            $eq: [
              "$memref",
              "$$membershipNumber"
            ]
          },
          
        }
      },
      {
        "$lookup": {
          "from": "emails",
          "localField": "user_id",
          "foreignField": "click",
          "as": "clicks"
        }
      },
      {
        "$project": {
          "_id": 1,
          "membershipNumber": 1,
          "an_user_id": "$user_id",
          "n_email_clicks": {
            $size: "$clicks"
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    as: "details"
  }
},
{
  $replaceRoot: {
    newRoot: {
      $mergeObjects: [
        {
          $arrayElemAt: [
            "$details",
            0
          ]
        },
        "$$ROOT"
      ]
    }
  }
},
{
  $project: {
    details: 0
  }
}])
```

Working example - https://mongoplayground.net/p/yrFsNp44hpi

Comment: hi @s7vr, thanks for your reply. i like this, this is definitely getting there. i tested your original query in the mongo playground and it worked. i then copied it into python, but i'm getting the following pymongo error: `TypeError: pipeline must be a list`  - which is weird, because it obviously *is* a list.

Comment: The edited version of your query isn't working for me, it's giving me the following error: `TypeError: aggregate() takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given`.

Comment: no worries - I don't think we need to put it in a [] for it to run from mongodb console or playground but I now added [] and updated the working example link. Both the issues you mentioned above are related to format. Give this new one a try pls.

Comment: cool. the query seems to be working (rather - executing), but it hits the size limit now... is there anything i can do to avert this? maybe i need to `$group` at the end, or throw an `$unwind` in there somewhere? this is the error: `OperationFailure: Total size of documents in emails matching pipeline's $lookup stage exceeds 104857600 bytes, full error: {'ok': 0.0, 'errmsg': "Total size of documents in emails matching pipeline's $lookup stage exceeds 104857600 bytes", 'code': 4568, 'codeName': 'Location4568'}`

Comment: yeah - we can add the unwind followed by group for counting - here is the updated link - https://mongoplayground.net/p/JHukuiDrirD. Also accounted for case when there is no emails for a user and output the value as 0

Comment: hi there! v cool. thanks.  
i basically got it to work now - but there's one major issue remaining. my original `members` collection has A LOT of random stuff in it, which I don't need for this, and I think it's what's causing the filesize error when running on the real database. How can I get rid of this stuff -- just run a `$project` right at the top of the aggregation?

Comment: yep - run the project at the top to limit the fields you would like to carry forward in the pipeline.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239275/discussion-between-nikuom-and-s7vr).

Comment: You could use https://mongoplayground.net/p/SoYf1ZpcHA6. It is pretty much more of the same.